# What is the value of $[(1^ {-2/3}) + (2^ {-2/3}) + (3^ {-2/3}) + … + (1000^ {-2/3})] $? Where $[x]$ stands for the greatest integer function.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, summation, special-functions

> What is the value of 
>   $$[(1^ {-2/3}) + (2^ {-2/3}) + (3^ {-2/3}) + … + (1000^ {-2/3})]?$$ 
>   where $[x]$ stands for the greatest integer function.

P. S :  I ran a code on my PC to find that the quantity inside the [ ] function is approximately equal to $27.5$ , thus $[27.5] = 27$. I am however Looking for a mathematical way to approximate the sum, instead of having run a code.

Comment: Try approximating it with an integral.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$S:=\sum_{k=1}^{1000} k^{-2/3}\ .$$
Then
$$S<1+\int_1^{1000}x^{-2/3}\>dx=1+3x^{1/3}\biggr|_1^{1000}=28\ .$$
In the same way
$$S>1+\int_2^{1001}x^{-2/3}\>dx=28+\int_{1000}^{1001}x^{-2/3}\>dx-\int_1^2x^{-2/3}\>dx>27\ ,$$
since the first "correcting integral" on the right is smaller than the second, and the second smaller than $1$. It follows that
$$\lfloor S\rfloor=27\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that 
$$S-1=\sum_{k=1}^{999}(k+1)^{-2/3}< \sum_{k=1}^{999}\int_{k}^{k+1}x^{-2/3}\,dx< \sum_{k=1}^{999}k^{-2/3}=S-\frac{1}{100}$$
where $S=\sum_{k=1}^{1000}k^{-2/3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Making the problem more general
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-\frac 23}=H_n^{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}$$ where appears generalized harmonic numbers.

Using asymptotics
$$S_n=3n^{\frac 13}+\zeta \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\frac {1 }{2n^{\frac 23} }-\frac {1 }{18n^{\frac 53} }+\frac {1 }{243n^{\frac {11}3} }+\cdots$$ If $n=1000$, $\frac {1 }{2n^{\frac 23} }=\frac 1{200}$ and we can admit that it would not impact the result. So the two first terms are sufficient and $\zeta \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=-2.44758\approx -\frac 52$ making
$$S_{1000}\sim 30 -\frac 52=27.5$$ which is what you obtained.

Comment: But where did you get the value of $\zeta(\frac23)$? I think the OP is looking for a method which can be done purely with pen and paper (and knowledge), without external resources.